Why is my performance low even with a high accuracy on chess.com?
I am a chess beginner and recently played a game on chess.com in which I had an accuracy of 90.6% which is even higher than some games of GMs on the site. However , the elo performance was still 1300 even though elo performance of those GMs was more than 2000 with an accuracy lower than this. Why is it like this and how does it work?
Here's a picture of game review : 

Try reproducing this game, but with black resigning after move 10 and seeing what it gives.  My understanding is that playing good in 'garbage time' inflates accuracy, but not ELO.

Most likely you didn't have the opportunity to play any tactics; I'd say this is rather normal since your opponent blundered the game rather early. You can think of the accuracy as how close you played to the best computer move. The ELO ratting is how good at chess you played the game, if you're opponent plays poorly, than you don't really need a high level of skill to beat them, the moves are rather obvious and do not need much thought, whereas if you found some sort of skewer or fork, or you made a brilliant sacrifice to reveal a discovered attack, I believe that would increase your ELO rating of the game.
in short generally High ELO = High accuracy, however the same does not hold true vice versa here's a game that you might find interesting
https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/110727712659?tab=review&move=70
both players had a lower accuracy than your game, but both players had higher ELO ratings, because their moves in essence, were more interesting.
I'm not certain if more interesting is the right choice of words, think of their moves as more complex out of necessity.
Accuracy is how well you scored on the test, whereas ELO is how creative the answers were. Though in your case the questions were so straightforward that you did not have a chance to give creative answers.

Please do not answer questions you simply do not know the answer of. The answer is that the predicted rating of the player is based on his/her actual rating +/- a certain number. So if your rating is 800, but you are actually a GM-smurf, the game will only precict ~1300 because of the simple reason that it can't predict more than +500 (I do not know the exact numbers but it should be around this).

Could you maybe elaborate on that idea, because it sounds to me as if you are saying that chess.com has a function where  gameELO = (PlayerELO) + (x); where X is some magic integer that maxes out at 500, my answer is based on my observations and analysis of games. If chess.com has some sort of documentation that supports your claim, I would find it interesting to read
